# GNU Radio - Export peak power values using HackRF

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I start working with GNU Radio and HackRF One SDR for an university project and I'm still a little bit lost. 
I'm using the HackRF One as a spectrum analyzer, specifically at about 868 MHz, because I'm using an Avalanche Transceiver (ARVA Beacon) which works at W-Link frequency (868 MHz). That signal source is a powerful signal peak at this frequency approximately every 5 seconds.

With GNU Radio I'm just trying to capture and later export into a file the peak power values (in dB) of this signal. So I want to set a threshold, capture the peak values of this signal continuously until I stop the programme and store them in a file.

I've tried to follow some similar tutorials but I'm not able to get a proper solution.

If someone could help me, I'll be so grateful!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about export the I/Q data of the signal, and then apply Hilbert transform?

Comment: Thanks for answering, how can I export the I/Q data? Out of GNU Radio?

Comment: Please use `file sink` block in GNU Radio.